# Unable to get prettier to format nicely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, prettier

I am having some difficulity with prettier. I use a husky pre-commit to format files, which runs `prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx}\"`

This works as in prettier is ran, but it is applying some really bizzare formatting.

For example the below JSX:

```
<Col cols={6}>
  <Note>This is a piece of text within a 6 col wrapper</Note>
</Col>
```

After prettier has ran:

```
<Col
    cols={
      6
    }
>
  <Note>
    This is 
    a piece
    of text
    within a
    6 col
    wrapper
  </Note>
</Col>
```

My prettier config is:

```
{
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": true,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "arrowParens": "always"
}
```

I have tried lots of different settings within `.prettierrc' but nothing is stopping almost everything from being dropped onto a new line which is making it really difficult to navigate through my files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: For the JSX snippet that you included, is it at the left-most column of your file? Prettier tries its best to fit your code into 80 columns, so if that code is very indented (say, with 15+ indents) then it will get "squished."

Comment: Put your JSX into the [Prettier playground](https://prettier.io/playground/) and it didn't change it at all

Answer (score 1):

Prettier tries to fit your code into [a certain number of columns](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width). Take a look at this example file:

```js
const nestedElement = (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <div
                                                                            key={
                                                                                6
                                                                            }
                                                                        >
                                                                            <div>
                                                                                This
                                                                                is
                                                                                a
                                                                                piece
                                                                                of
                                                                                text
                                                                                within
                                                                                a
                                                                                6
                                                                                col
                                                                                wrapper
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

One way to combat this is to pull out your specific JSX chunk into a separate variable, like this:

```js
const innerElement = (
    <div key={6}>
        <div>This is a piece of text within a 6 col wrapper</div>
    </div>
);

const nestedElement = (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        {
                                                                            innerElement
                                                                        }
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

That way, you can get the element itself looking better while still inserting it into a very deeply nested JSX tree.

Of course, your code will probably look more like this anyway:

```js
const inner1 = (
    <div key={6}>
        <div>This is a piece of text within a 6 col wrapper</div>
    </div>
);

const inner2 = (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>{inner1}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const inner3 = (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>{inner2}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const nestedElement = (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>{inner3}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Breaking it up into more manageable pieces can often help the formatting and also the readability.